# Create NSWindow from nib name

Tags: cocoa, swift

I'm trying to create an NSWindow from an own nib file but it seems to be harder than I expected...

The NSWindowController offers an `init(windowNibName: String?)` method which could be overridden by a sub-class. It doesn't seem to be possible to invoke the base class' `init(windowNibName: String?)` without overriding it (the compiler shows an error message that there is no initializer which takes that String argument).

But when overriding this `init(...)` method you have to follow the initialization chain which forces you to call a designated initializer. This designated initializer is `init(window: NSWindow!)`.

And this is where I'm stuck at the moment... it seems like I **have** to create an NSWindow object (somehow) in order to pass it to the designated initializer.
But I don't know how to create an NSWindow from a nib file.

Does anybody have any clue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's bug, I think.

Create your own init method and load xib file yourself, like this:

```
class MyWindowController: NSWindowController {

    init() {
        super.init(window: nil)

        /* Load window from xib file */
        NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("MyWindow", owner: self, topLevelObjects: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to work. The `loadNibNamed(...)` method seems to load the nib (at least it returns `true`) but the window within the controller is still NIL. Do I have to set the window explicitly after loading the NIB?

Comment: This didn't work for me at all, TheGoonie's answer did.

Answer (score 5):

I found my mistake...

I put my own WindowController as "File's Owner" into the NIB file but just forgot to link its "window" property to the window within the NIB (in Interface Builder).

Now it works as it should.

Thanks @juniperi

Comment: Also be sure to set nib's FileOwner to use the custom NSWindowController class in the identity inspector, drag the window outlet to the window and then store the custom NSWindowController instance as a property on a class, otherwise it gets garbage collected.